# How can I prevent DNS resolution of a name?

Tags: networking, dns

Blocking DNS resolution is a very crude but simple safety net I put around websites that I have moral issues with — by blocking DNS resolution I prevent a connection being made to the remote host in the first place, which greatly reduces their ability to do much of anything with my data, or my eyeballs. This isn't about advertisers; it's really easy for ad networks to make this sort of thing ineffective and unscalable. Ad blockers try to discard the ads and keep the contents; I want *neither.*

How can I achieve that, or a similarly effective barrier, on unrooted Android M?

Comment: You can't on an rooted device, even if rooted you can only control WiFi DNS resolution, but not on mobile data.

Comment: @acejavelin He could set up **iptables** and discard any packet going to or coming from a certain website, no?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman True... I was just narrowing in on the DNS thing, still requires root either way.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman yeah, doing it at the IP address basis is extremely brittle